# How to match case the undeprecated apply-method of scala.xml.Elem

Tags: xml, scala, pattern-matching

in order to update a child on a xml node you can do this (other SO-ticket ref missing here):

```
val node:Node = <item><category>1</category></item>
val root = node match {
  case Elem(p,l,a,s, child @ _*) ⇒ Elem(p,l,a,s,child.filter(_.label != "category") ++ <category>2</category>:_* )
  case _ ⇒ node // error case
}
```

This gives a deprecated warning, as one should use the Elem method with explicit naming of `minimizeEmpty` as 5th parameter:

```
val node:Node = <item><category>1</category></item>
val root = node match {
  case Elem(p,l,a,s,m,child @ _*) ⇒ Elem(p,l,a,s,m,child.filter(_.label != "category") ++ <category>2</category>:_* )
  case _ ⇒ node // error case
}
```

This however does not work, as it always applies the deconstructing of the apply method without the explicit Boolean parameter, hence `m` always gets the type `Node` and nothing fits.

So how can I help the compiler to select the correct Constructor/apply-method? (scala 2.12.1)

Not working:

```
case Elem(p,l,a,s,m:Boolean,child @ _*)
case Elem(p,l,a,s,m @(_:Boolean),child @ _*) 
case Elem(p,l,a,s,m @Boolean,child @ _*)
```

All tell me, that m must be Node

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the deprecation warning, it's with the companion object's apply method, and not with the pattern match constructor:

```
> set scalacOptions += "-deprecation"
> console
scala> import scala.xml._

scala> val node:Elem = <item><category>1</category></item>

scala> node match {
         case Elem(p,l,a,s, child @ _*) ⇒ Elem(p,l,a,s,child.filter(_.label != "category") ++ <category>2</category>:_* )
       }
<console>:17: warning: method apply in object Elem is deprecated: Use the other apply method in this object
  case Elem(p,l,a,s, child @ _*) ⇒ Elem(p,l,a,s,child.filter(_.label != "category") ++ <category>2</category>:_* )
                                   ^
```

It might be useful to just use a variable-binding parameter with `@`:

```
scala> node match {
     |   case e @ Elem(p,l,a,s, child @ _*) ⇒ Elem(p,l,a,s,e.minimizeEmpty,child.filter(_.label != "category") ++ <category>2</category>:_* )
     | }
res1: scala.xml.Elem = <item><category>2</category></item>
```

I'm a little surprised the pattern match for `Elem` has this defect.  For some reason `Elem` was converted to a companion object with an `apply` method, in 2007, from a case class.  In 2012, the second `apply` method was added and deprecated the first.

Functions in Scala support varargs, and they work well.  Case classes in Scala also support varargs.  In this case, this is with `apply` methods using varargs, and there are two of them.  The compiler supports the use of multiple `apply` methods, but how that interacts with varargs might makes pattern matching difficult.  I don't think the scala-xml maintainers understood the impact of their changes, with respect to pattern matching, when they added a second apply method to add new parameters.

Comment: The latter solution is almost what I used, thanks for this enhancement. When I read your answer correctly, this is a bug/defect in Scala? I witnessed this previously with overloaded functions where one had a `*`-parameter?

Comment: @Jan Good question.  I've answered it by adding another paragraph to the answer above.

Comment: our nice solution with `e @ Elem…` does not work, when type of `node` is actually `Node` … So I stick to my `node.asInstanceOf[Elem].minimizeEmpty` variant :)

Comment: @Jan That's strange. I guess I don't know how that could happen.  Isn't an `Elem` a subclass of `Node`.  How would you be in the `Elem` case and get a `Node`?

Comment: How shall I know? I was as surprised as you seem. But the compiler clearly stated, that e was of type Node.